# Facing Issue on Mapping Parent Child Relation Table using Automapper in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper, repository-pattern

--------------- PARENT MODEL CLASS ------------------------

```
public class TechCategory : AuditableBaseEntity
{
    public int TechCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string TechCategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Initial { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TechSubcategory> TechSubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

---------------- CHILD MODEL CLASS ---------------------------

```
public class TechSubcategory : AuditableBaseEntity
{
public int TechSubcategoryId { get; set; }
public string TechSubcategoryName { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string Initial { get; set; }
public int? TechCategoryId { get; set; }
public virtual TechCategory TechCategory { get; set; }
}
```

--------------------- DTO CLASS -------------------------------

```
public class TechSubCategoryDto
{
public int TechSubcategoryId { get; set; }
public string TechSubcategoryName { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string Initial { get; set; }
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
public string CategoryName { get; set; }
public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

----------------------- MAPPER CLASS --------------------------

```
public class AutoMapperConfig: Profile
{
    public AutoMapperConfig()
    {
        CreateMap<TechCategory, TechCategoryDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<TechSubcategory, TechSubCategoryDto\>()
        .ForMember(x => x.CategoryId, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.TechCategoryId))
        .ForMember(x => x.CategoryName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.TechCategory.TechCategoryName))
        .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

------------------------ CONTROLLER CLASS ----------------------

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("All", Name = "GetAllSubCategory")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TechSubCategoryDto>>> GetSubCategoryAsync()
{
var subCat = await _subCategoryRepository.GetAllAsync();
var catDto = _mapper.Map<List<TechSubCategoryDto>>(subCat);
return Ok(catDto);
}
```

---

Here is my output screen in swagger

It maps only [categoryId] but does not map the [categoryName], only null showing in [categoryname]

Please help to resolve the issue...
[image]

Comment: You, first get all the entities and then map them into dtos, that's why the related entities don't load in the first query.

Comment: can you please elaborate the answer.....

Comment: By default, lazy loading in EF is disabled, so when you call `GetAllAsync` you get the results `TechCategory` navigation is null. So when you you try to map from there it will be null. So if you map (or precisely project) entities before executing the query this time mapped navigation properties will be included or you can modify `GetAllAsync` to Include the navigation property beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is **not related to Automapper**. The `_subCategoryRepository.GetAllAsync()` method will not fetch parent model "TechCategory" until you explicitly specify it while executing database query using entity framework core.

Refer eager-loading in ef-core from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#eager-loading)

If you want to get values of "TechCategory" model while fetching "TechSubCategory" model. You need to create a method in your TechSubCategory Repositiory as following:

**Repository**

```
public async IEnumerable<TechSubCategory> GetAllIncludeTechCategoryAsync()
{
    return await _dbContext.TechSubCategory.Include(x => x.TechCategory).ToListAsync();
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("All", Name = "GetAllSubCategory")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TechSubCategoryDto>>> GetSubCategoryAsync()
{
    var subCat = await _subCategoryRepository.GetAllIncludeTechCategoryAsync();
    var catDto = _mapper.Map<List<TechSubCategoryDto>>(subCat);
    return Ok(catDto);
}
```